# How can I set the width of the Edit Button col in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that sets the `AutoGenerateEditButton="true"`

How can I set the width of the resulting column?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you can set the width when the Edit button is auto-generated.
But you *can* set it if you add the *CommandField*.

Steps:

1. Set AutoGenerateEditButton back to false
2. Expand the GridView Tasks window using the funny little arrow button in the top right of the GridView
3. Select 'Edit Columns'
4. Expand the 'Command Field' node in the Available Fields list.
5. Select 'Edit, Update, Cancel' and then click the Add button
6. Make sure 'Edit, Update, Cancel' is selected in the Selected Fields list
7. Expand the 'ItemStyle' node in the CommandField properties list
8. Shazaam, there is your width property down near the bottom.

The Command buttons (edit, cancel, update) will still behave as if you had auto-generated them, you just get more control over the layout.

[image: Gridview CommandField]

Comment: @Ken Ray: Sorry about that ; )  Gotta be quick these days huh!?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you don't have direct control over the column containing the edit button - because of the "AutoGenerate" in the property you are setting, it is rendered automatically.

An alternative is to set `AutoGenerateEditButton="False"`, and define a column containing the Edit command button yourself.  Then in the markup, you can set the width of that column yourself.

Comment: That is right , we cannot set/edit width pr height in buttons that are rendered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

12+ years later, we can do this with CSS:

```
td:first-child
{
    width: 5%;
}
```